# struct "_typeobject" has no field "tp_name" in Cython Example

Tags: python, c, cython, embedding

I'm trying to learn how to [Embedd Cython modules in c Applications](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/embedding.html) from the Cython Website, I have Literally copy pasted the entire example and it doesn't work. it gives me a `struct "_typeobject" has no field "tp_name"` Error every time, I am new to all this and I'm hoping someone could explain what I'm missing.

I don't know if it is relevant but I'm using a setup.py file to feed in my arguments

**Setup.py**

[Contents of setup.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cluc.png)

**Main.c**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkJLV.png)

**Embedded.h**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kt3ia.png)

Comment: I suspect this isn't the *first* error message you get. That's probably what we need to see. I've I had to guess it's probably failing to find "Python.h"

Comment: A few days ago it was but I linked it with my python3.10 header files, so I tweaked the code a bit for it to find them

Comment: I think it'd be very useful to have the complete error message and the setup.py file you're using.

Comment: The errors in "embedded" look like your _editor_ doesn't know about Python.h. I actually suspect it compiles fine when you run setup.py

Comment: The errors in main.c look like the important ones. They're telling you that you have to give it a link path to libpython. I'm afraid I'm not sure how to do that with MSVC but that's probably what you should focus on